# Unreasonable rejected edit suggestion?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have asked a [question today at math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2974707/representing-integer-as-product-of-2n-and-an-odd-number). I got a nice answer in the comments by [Marco](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/582590/marco). He changed his comment to an answer, and explained the general idea, but not the special case to answer my question.

I edited his question to show the concrete answer to my question.

Most surprisingly, the edit was rejected.

[image]

In my opinion, this edit made sense, and with this edit I would accept the answer. Thus I believe that the two users who rejected it have not been careful enough.

Am I right in making such an edit, or is the rejection correct? If such edits are fine, please tell me how I can not improve the answer of Marco? Thank you

Comment: If you give "-1", please specify in the comment why that is. Thank you for your constructive contribution.

Comment: I'd like to thank the two users who voted to reject the edit.

Comment: Note that there are many answerers that provide all tools and how they relate when they answer, i.e., they create the "recipe" for a solution, sufficient for a good answer, and leave the asker to execute the recipe/do the cooking to arrive at a particular application of a general methodology and its answer. And they leave out "the final answer" intentionally.  So inserting an answer into their post "conflicts with the author's intent", a reason for rejecting a post.

Answer (score 15):

The edit goes too far for an edit. You could have proposed the inclusion in a comment. 
If the author of the answer does not want it in their post, you could then write your own answer.

Note that if the author of the post is in favor of your edit, they can just override the reviewers decision. Thus, it makes sense to err on the side of caution when reviewing.

Comment: OK, thank you for this information, i understand and agree with this logic. Does the author of the post see my edit, even through it was rejected by other math.SE users?

Comment: Yes, IIRC, they get an inbox notification about it and then can decide.